# BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, socket.io

I have a problem with ObjectID.
I connect Socket.io in my app

This is file for Socket.io connection and I added Car.findOne() method to fetch id like owner and get data for car :
app.js
// socket connection

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server);
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    console.log('Connected to client');
    // listen to object ID event
    
    socket.on('ObjectID',(ObjectID)=>{
        console.log('User ID is: ', ObjectID);
        Car.findOne({owner:ObjectID})
        .then((car)=>{
            socket.emit('car',car);
        });
    });
```

After that I added car event in script.js to show car

```
// connect Socket.io

$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io();

    // connect client to server
    socket.on('connect', function(socket){
        console.log('Connected to server');
    });

    // emit user id
    var ObjectID = $('#ObjectID').val();
    socket.emit('ObjectID', ObjectID);
    
    // listen to car event
    socket.on('car',function(car){
        console.log(car);
        // make an ajax request to fetch latitude and longitude
        
    });

    // disconnect from server
    socket.on('disconnect', function(socket){
        console.log('Disconnected from server');
    });
});
```

This is car collection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const carSchema = new Schema({
    owner: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    mark: {
        type: String
    },
    model: {
        type: String
    },
    year: {
        type: Number
    },
    type: {
        type: String
    },
    pricePerWeek: {
        type: Number
    },
    pricePerHour: {
        type: Number
    },
    image: [{
        imageUrl: {
            type: String
        }
    }],
    location: {
        type: String
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    lat: {
        type: Number
    },
    lng: {
        type: Number
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Car',carSchema);
```

But after run the app, I become this error:

```
    CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" (type string) at path "owner" for model "Car"
    at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4927:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:5026:15)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\app.js:333:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:470:12)
    at Socket.emitUntyped (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\socket.io\dist\typed-events.js:69:22)        
    at C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\socket.io\dist\socket.js:703:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:76:11) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '""',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '',
  path: 'owner',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer     
      at new BSONTypeError (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
      at new ObjectId (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:67:23)
      at castObjectId (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:246:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1201:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1648:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1636:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1612:20)
      at cast (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:349:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (C:\Users\201217040\Documents\CarRental\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:5357:12),        
  valueType: 'string'
}
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Edit:
I understood this:
If sockets tries to catch user ID while user is logged out, it will return user ID as a empty string “”. If you want to emit new event as soon as user logged in, you can run a function as soon as user visits the profile or website. We have a socket connection and disconnect events in both server and client in script.js. We can emit new event as soon as client connects to socket. Add a function inside socket connection event. The question is , how can I create this function?